# I have tried to implement notification bell icon my admin portal

Tags: angular

ERROR in projects/boss/src/app/secure/ui/toolbar/toolbar.component.html:5:13 - error NG8001: 'shared-notification-widget-count' is not a known element:
1. If 'shared-notification-widget-count' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'shared-notification-widget-count' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
5             <shared-notification-widget-count></shared-notification-widget-count>
```

Comment: Please add some part of your code

Comment: You have to import the 'shared-notification-widget-count' in your module.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common scenarios that cause this error:

- You forgot to add the `shared-notification-widget-count.component` to your modules declaration
- Or you have declared this component in another module, that you want to use and then need to import the module

> For a detailed answer, please add a code